# Unit Test - call navigation from viewcontroller is nil

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

When I call navigation controller from view controller, navigation controller become nil.
How can I access navigation controller?

```
override func setUp() {
    self.viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
    self.viewController.loadView()
    XCTAssertNotNil(self.viewController.navigationController,"Navigation is nil")
}
```

Comment: it should be self.navigationController not self.viewController.navigationController

Comment: self is FirstViewControllerTest script for unit test. If using self.navigationController is will become Value of type 'FirstViewControllerTest' had no member for 'navigationController'

Answer (score 1):

To test navigationController, you need to add it to array of view controllers.

```
func testViewControllerShouldHaveNavigationController() {
    let viewController = UIViewController()
    let navigation = UINavigationController()
    navigation.viewControllers = [viewController]
    XCTAssertNotNil(viewController.navigationController)
}
```